# Groovy : RegEx for matching Alphanumeric and underscore and dashes

Tags: regex, grails, groovy

I am working on Grails 1.3.6 application. I need to use Regular Expressions to find matching strings.

It needs to find whether a string has anything other than Alphanumeric characters or "-" or "_" or "*"

An example string looks like:

```
SDD884MMKG_JJGH1222
```

What i came up with so far is,

```
String regEx = "^[a-zA-Z0-9*-_]+\$"
```

The problem with above is it doesn't search for special characters at the end or beginning of the string.

I had to add a "\" before the "$", or else it will give an compilation error.

```
- Groovy:illegal string body character after dollar sign;
```

Can anyone suggest a better RegEx to use in Groovy/Grails?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is unescaped hyphen in the middle of the character class. Fix it by using:

```
String regEx = "^[a-zA-Z0-9*_-]+\$";
```

Or even shorter:

```
String regEx = "^[\\w*-]+\$";
```

By placing an unescaped `-` in the middle of character class your regex is making it behave like a range between `*` (ASCII 42) and `_` (ASCII 95), matching everything in this range.

Comment: I still get a compilation error:  `illegal string body character after dollar sign;
   solution: either escape a literal dollar sign "\$5" or bracket the value expression "${5}" @ line 114, column 16.
     s = d.matches("^[\\w*-]+$");`
                  ^

Answer (score 4):

In Groovy the `$` char in a string is used to handle replacements (e.g. `Hello ${name}`).  As these so called `GString`s are only handled, if the string is written surrounding it with `"`-chars you have to do extra escaping.

Groovy also allows to write your strings without that feature by surrounding them with `'` (single quote).  Yet the easiest way to get a regexp is the syntax with `/`.

```
assert "SDD884MMKG_JJGH1222" ==~ /^[a-zA-Z0-9*-_]+$/
```

See [Regular Expressions](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Regular+Expressions) for further "shortcuts".

The other points from @anubhava remain valid!

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to reverse it:

```
String regEx = "^[^a-zA-Z0-9\\*\\-\\_]+\$" /* This matches everything _but_ alnum and *-_ */
```